# Updating object with related objects with EntityFramework 6

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, entity

I'm trying to integrate EF6 database first into a project, which uses legacy sql. I have a problem with the following tables:

```
Product(ID, Name) -- this translates to a Product entity
User(ID, Name) -- this translates to a User entity
UserXProduct(UserID, ProductID) -- this translates into navigational properties
```

Note that I can't access UserXProduct table through entity framework, because it somehow didn't generate a new table, just the navigational properties. I use the following code to update the table:

```
var entity = ctx.User.SingleOrDefault(rec => rec.ID == updRec.ID);
if(entity != null){
    entity.Product = ctx.Product.Where(rec => updRec.ProductIDs.Contains(rec.ID)).ToList();
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

It works the first time around, when the User record doesn't have any Products associated with it, whenever I add another product to the list, it fails.

SQL Profiler shows, that Entity Framework tries to INSERT UserID and ProductID into UserXProduct table, not just the new one, but all of them. It should either delete previous connections or insert only new ones. How can I achieve such behaviour?

Comment: Simply, when you get entity you have related products with the user. So you can compare `entity.Product` list and `ctx.Product.Where(rec => updRec.ProductIDs.Contains(rec.ID)).ToList();` lists to find new ones and if there some new one(s) `entity.Product.Add()` or `entity.Product.AddRange()`

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but I guess there's no way around it.

Comment: I'm not sure, didn't test it, but maybe Union() method will help.